# The HTTP request was forbidden with client authentication scheme 'Anonymous' WCF SSL

Tags: wcf, ssl, ssl-certificate, x509certificate, http-status-code-403

First of all let me describe my system.
I have a virtual server (Windows Server 2012 R2 with IIS 8.5) with two running systems.
One is for receiving Informations from Devices and the other one is for presenting and combining the users information with the device information. 
The two systems are combined by a reference (via VS2012).

---

**Problem:**
If I have a look on my website for the system which gives me the user and device information in get an error, so I try to debug it on my own pc.
While debugging I want to access the service to display me all devices and it gives me:

System.ServiceModel.Security.MessageSecurityException
**The HTTP request was forbidden with client authentication scheme 'Anonymous'.**

I also have a WCF-Tracelog which shows me:
[WCF-Tracelog](https://i.stack.imgur.com/EEDeE.png)

---

I'm now facing that problem for days and I was browsing stackoverflow a lot. I guess that it should be a problem with my certificates. At the moment I got a SSL-certificate (received from my university). I also "registered" it to a specified port and added the right bindings in my IIS (IIS 8.5). I am very new to WCF,IIS,SOAP and certificates but I guess my problem is the understanding of the certificates.

---

**Question:**
Which certificates do I have to create for my "Server-Website/Client"-System and which do I have to create for my own "Client" and where do I have to copy them (at the moment I'm familiar with the MMC => Snap-In)? And where do I need to keep my SSL-certificate located?

---

I hope someone faced the same Problem and can help me to fix this soon. Sorry for my bad english and if you need more information let me know!

---

**EDIT:**
I fixed my certificate-problem but now i receive 403.4 (SSL is required)

Comment: In IIS management console go to your WCF/site/whatever application, then go to authentication and enable anonymous authentication.

Comment: Anonymous authentication is enabled in IIS for both websites

Comment: I just fixed it. If anyone else is facing the same problems check this link: [Redirect from http to https](https://www.sslshopper.com/iis7-redirect-http-to-https.html)

Answer (score 0):

my problem solved, i have enabled "IP Address and Domain Restriction" and i added an "allow" option to this section, thus another ip got that error